# wpf adding new items to a listbox

Tags: wpf, listbox, wpf-controls, binding, observablecollection

Sorry if the Syntax is off, i typed this on Notepad, (temp. issues with computer with VS)

i have a class `Movie` with a `Title` property, i have

```
 Dim movieList = New ObservableCollection(of Movie) 

 Private Sub SelectMovie(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)

  For Each m As Movie in movieList
    If lb1.SelectedItem = "New" Then
      m.Add(New Movie()) 
    End If
   Next

 End Sub
```

movieList was initialized with temp values, last one being **"New"**.
In the constructor i iterated through movielist and put stuff in the listbox.

```
lb1.Items.Add(m)
```

In the **MainWindow.xaml** i have

```
 <Grid Name="moviePage" > 
   <ListBox Name="lb1" SelectionChanged="SelectMovie">
 </Grid>
```

I'm aware that this approach is wrong as I'm modifying a list while using it, but i can't seem to find a way around this.

The idea is to simply have the listbox show a bunch of movies, with the ability to add a new movie if **"New"** is selected from the list.

Comment: What's your question? Does your code not work?

Comment: a way to do this that won't cause errors. I was getting an error stating that i can't add stuff to the array while i'm iterating through it. My comp. that has VS is having issues right now, so i just typed this up using what i remember was happening. I can't think of anything else right now, all ideas are appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working code sample:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _movies = new ObservableCollection<Movie>(
        new[]
        {
            new Movie { Name = "Foo" },
            new Movie { Name = "Bar" },
            new Movie { Name = "(New)" },
        });
    lb1.ItemsSource = _movies;
}

ObservableCollection<Movie> _movies;

private void SelectMovie(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedMovie = lb1.SelectedItem as Movie;
    if (selectedMovie == null) return;

    if (selectedMovie.Name == "(New)")
    {
        var newMovie = new Movie { Name = "Untitled" };
        _movies.Insert(_movies.Count - 1, newMovie);
        lb1.SelectedItem = newMovie;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Having said that, I don't believe this is the right approach for what you're doing. I think you're better off changing the template for the ListBox so that it shows the list of items it's bound to, and then a "New" button or link at the bottom (outside of the list).

Here's a very simple example:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb1" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectionChanged="SelectMovie">
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <ItemsPresenter />
                <Button Click="AddMovie>New Movie</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
</ListBox>
```

So now you have a ListBox which includes a button to create a new movie. In your `AddMovie` event handler you can add a new `Movie` instance to the list and select it.